# How many SD card insertions/ejections does an average socket tolerate?

Tags: sd-card

I notice that there are a lot of question that allude to SD card and/or slot problems.

Some say their Pi suddenly quits booting, etc.

So my question is:  How many SD card insertions/ejections does an average socket tolerate?

Comment: It might be worth to split this question into two separate questions for the "old" Pis with standard SD cards and the newer models featuring micro-SD. Back in the olden days some users recommended to use micro-SD cards with adapters (and thus not remove the card from the slot at the Pi) when frequently changing the card. But then again I am not sure that was a real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe any damage to the mini-SD slots on a Rpi would be most likely caused due to improper usage - such as inserting the card upside down and trying to jam it in, etc.

But in terms of actual ratings, the best answer I found on this is related to photography, where people insert and remove their cards much more often than we do in our Raspberry Pis.

[How many SDHC card insertions/ejections does an average camera slot withstand?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/how-many-sdhc-card-insertions-ejections-does-an-average-camera-slot-withstand)

And the best answer is excerpted here:

> *Note: the links in the list below are likely to go stale, as manufacturers and distributors often change their numbering/indexing;
>   and as parts go out of production*.
>
> Not knowing which manufacturer(s) provides the SD card connectors for
>   your camera, the best you can do is find datasheet specs from a wide
>   variety of manufacturers, and make your own best guess. When I
>   searched for "SD card insert eject cycle", I came up with some of the
>   following:
>
> 1. 3000 – 5000 cycles (various SIM & MicroSD card connectors, no standard SD): [SMK Electronics](https://www.smkusa.com/usa/featured_products/mem/)
> 2. 10,000 cycles @ 400–600 cycles/hour: [Hirose Electronics (Mouser)](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/185/DM1_catalog-773319.pdf)
> 3. "10,000 mating cycles are guaranteed": [Kyocera 5138 series connector](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0676008001_MEMORY_CARD_SOCKET.xml)
> 4. 10,000 mating cycles max durability: [Molex][5]

Note that this is talking about the full-size SD card slots.

I have found it impossible to locate specific data on the exact type of slot used in the Raspberry Pi.

So my WAG (Wild Guess) would be certainly dozens if not hundreds of times.